# Issue publishing Xamarin Forms Android app as bundle to Play Store - docs out of date

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, google-play-console, submission

I want to publish my Xamarin Forms Android app, as a bundle, to the Play Store for initial testing and I'm following the Xamarin [instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/publishing/publishing-to-google-play/?tabs=macos) 'Publishing to Google Play' for Visual Studio for Mac.

I create a keystore and the next step is to create a Google API project in my Google Play Console (where I had already created my app), to get an OAUTH client ID and secret for Visual Studio to use. Problem is, the Xamarin documentation dated 8 July 2021 is out of date and, despite massive Googling, I'm lost trying to figure out an equivalent in the new Google Play Console layout.

I reach *API Access* on the Setup dropdown, and under Linked Google Cloud project I select *Create new project*. Here the options are to *Configure OAUTH consent screen* and/or *Create new service account*.

I try *Configure OAUTH consent screen* but the prompts do not seem relevant to a publishing scenario and require Google verification, which seems over the top.

*Create new service account* appears possibly more relevant and I try that, on the Google Cloud Platform. After creating a new service account, I'm prompted to *'Grant this service account access to Google Play Console Developer so that it has permission to complete specific actions on the resources in your project'*, which sounds promising.

The options here are *Select a role* and *Add condition*. This is where I have no idea how to proceed further. Am I on the wrong track, or if on the right track, what should I do next?

Comment: Here is a publish sample app, you can refer to it https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/HelloWorldPublishing

Comment: @AdrainZhu-MSFT the actual issue is that following changes to Google Play Console, the Xamarin documentation is out of date and no longer useful in showing how to publish an Android app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I arrived at (edited).

1. Log in to Google Play Console and select your developer account.
2. On the Setup dropdown, choose *API access*.
3. Under *Linked Google Cloud Project*, select *Create new project* and *Link* project.
4. Click *Configure OAuth consent* screen.
5. Select User Type *External* and click *Create*.
6. Fill in App information, App domain, Authorised domain, Developer contact information, using details pertaining to your app.
7. Click *Save and Continue*.
8. Click *Add or Remove Scopes*, select *Google Play Android Developer API*, click *Update*.
9. Click *Save and Continue*.
10. Under *Test users*, click *Add Users*, add tester email addresses (Google accounts).
11. Click *Save and Continue*. Your OAuth consent screen details are displayed, under Google Could Platform > APIs and Services > OAuth consent screen.
12. Click *Back to Dashboard*. Return to the Google Play Console browser tab and, on the *API access* page, click *Refresh OAuth consent*. The screen updates.
13. Click *Create new OAuth client*. You’ll see some instructions. Before clicking *Done*, return to the Google Cloud Platform tab. Click *Credentials* and, on the *Create Credentials* dropdown, select *OAuthClientId* from the dropdown.
14. On the *Application type* dropdown, select *Desktop app* and give it a name.
15. Click *Create*. Your Client ID and Client Secret are displayed. Copy and store them securely, optionally download JSON for good measure, then click OK.
16. Return to the *API access* tab and, under *Create new OAuth client*, click *Done*. The OAuth Client ID will be displayed.
17. At any time, visit https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials to see your Client ID.

As a possibly simpler alternative, not requiring Client Id at all:

In Visual Studio, use Ad hoc publishing to store the signed .aab file in a folder. Then create a release in Google Play Console, dropping the .aab file when prompted.

Comment: Where do you find the "client secret"? I downloaded the Json, there is a ClientID, but I do not see a secret anywhere.

Comment: @tval If it did not show in step 15 above:

Comment: Google Play Console > login > API Access
Under OAuth Clients / Client ID, click on View on Google Cloud Platform
Under OAuth 2.0 Client Ids, click on your client - the secret is displayed